Enum being cast as integer despite Npgsql mapping
I have a table with a jsonb column containing a serialized array of objects where a property called Field is an enum called ActivityField.
I am mapping the enum as per https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/enum.html?tabs=with-datasource
var dataSourceBuilder = new NpgsqlDataSourceBuilder(connStr);
dataSourceBuilder.MapEnum<ActivityField>();
var dataSource = dataSourceBuilder.Build();

The enum is also registered with EFCore as follows
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.HasPostgresEnum<ActivityField>()...

However, it's still being cast as an integer when used in LINQ expressions such as
var analyticsQueriesWithClientsFilter = _db.AnalyticsQueries
  .Where(x => x.Filters.Any(f => f.Field == ActivityField.Clients));

as indicated by the following error message:
The LINQ expression 'f => (int)f.Field == 13' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.

What am I missing?
This is a net8.0 project using Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 8.0.8

How is _db being injected? If it is using a DbContext Factory then potentially the DbContext isn't being set up with the custom data source.

@StevePy The dbcontext is being injected as follows:
services.AddDbContext(options =>
options.UseNpgsql(dataSource).UseSnakeCaseNamingConvention());
There are no issues with this and all DB operations are working -- the only problem is the enum casting

As always, please post a fully runnable, minimal console program. A partial set of snippets as you've posted above may leave out important information and doesn't allow immediate repro'ing.

@ShayRojansky Could you please at least confirm whether enums within a JSONB column should be handled as such by EFCore after being mapped?
